# Laravel 8: Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravelcollective

I'm using Laravel 8, and I want to install Laravel Collective v5.7.

So at the Terminal I said:

`composer require "laravelcollective/html":"5.7.1"`

But it returns this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.7.1 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.7.1].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.
20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v8.37.0, required as ^8.12) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.37.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So what's going wrong ? How can I install that version of Laravel Collective properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the crucial information:

```
laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires illuminate/view 5.7.*
```

v5.7 of that package requires Laravel 5.7, but your are using Laravel v8.

All versions since v6.2 are compatible with Laravel v8.